# could not locate an entity named 'Book' in this model. ios coredata error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, core-data, entity

Hi iam trying to implement a sample project with core data but when i tried to run this it crashing with  following message

```
"
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an entity named 'Book' in this model.'"
```

please following codes. I have implemented only these [image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create an entity named as "Book" for Core Data Model??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55641/discussion-between-bangalore-and-javed-iqbal).